# How to run Animated.Spring in external component call

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I'm trying to call ***Animated.Spring*** from a parent component and the function isn't running. How do you fix this issue?

It works within the component but not when called from outside. I'm using alerts to show that the function code does run but it skips the Animated call for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Animated, Button, Easing } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component {
  handlerSimpleCall = () => {
    //Calling a function of other class (without arguments)
    new Alerts().handleAnimation();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        }}>
        <Alerts />
        <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
          <Button
            title="Function Without Argument"
            onPress={this.handlerSimpleCall}
            color="#606070"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Alerts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(1)
  }

  handleAnimation = () => {
    this.animatedValue.setValue(0)
    alert("ASD")
    Animated.spring(this.animatedValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      friction: 1
    }).start()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Animated.View style={{ height: 150, width: 150, backgroundColor: 'red', transform: [{ scale: this.animatedValue }] }} />
        <View style={{ width: 100, marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Button onPress={this.handleAnimation} title='Press Me' />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [use a ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to refer to your component, rather than creating a `new Alerts()`.

I was able to make it work like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Animated, Button, Easing } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.alertRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        }}>
        <Alerts
          ref={this.alertRef}
        />
        <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
          <Button
            
            title="Function Without Argument"
            onPress={() => this.alertRef.current.handleAnimation()}
            color="#606070"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Alerts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(1)
  }

  handleAnimation = () => {
    this.animatedValue.setValue(0)
    alert("ASD")
    Animated.spring(this.animatedValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      friction: 1
    }).start()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Animated.View style={{ height: 150, width: 150, backgroundColor: 'red', transform: [{ scale: this.animatedValue }] }} />
        <View style={{ width: 100, marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Button onPress={this.handleAnimation} title='Press Me' />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why you need to use ref because the function still runs without it.

Comment: In your original code, you created a new, orphaned instance of `Alerts`. When you create a new instance, the function for the new instance runs, but it doesn't exist in the UI at all, so it doesn't affect the `Alerts` instance actually displayed in the `App` component. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, do you know how to run the function without using a constructor? I also tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your follow up question here. Do you mean my code snippet isn't working for you?